# Mapping a function over columns and rows without using nested apply

Tags: r, functional-programming, apply, purrr

I have a couple of dataframes and a vector like so:

```
set.seed(420)

df1 <- data.frame(matrix(rexp(50), nrow = 10, ncol = 5))
names(df1) <- paste0(rep("variable_", 5), 1:5)

df2 <- data.frame(matrix(rexp(50), nrow = 10, ncol = 5))
names(df2) <- paste0(rep("variable_", 5), 1:5)

vector1 <- data.frame(variable_a = rexp(10))
```

I would like to take a function which loops over both columns and rows of all 3 of my objects. But it seems that both `mapply` and `pmap` only take columns as inputs, and I have to make a nested function in order to get what I want:

```
#function
simple_function <- function(x,y,z) {
 sum((x + y) ^ z)
}

# nested map - quite ugly
map_dfc(1:5, function(n) {
  pmap(list(df1[n], vector1, df2[n]), simple_function)
})
```

Which gives me the required output as below:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 5
     X1    X2    X3    X4    X5
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  57.3  29.3  25.3  51.0  37.8
```

Is there a ways to rewrite the map function to avoid nesting?

Comment: I get different values from what you posted. Anyway, what's wrong with just `Map(simple_function,df1,vector1,df2)`?

Comment: If you strictly need a frame, then `as.data.frame(Map(...))`, since `Map` returns a list. Nice, @nicola.

Comment: Do you want `pmap_df(list(df1, list(vector1), df2), simple_function)`?

Comment: I think that @aosmith's solution is what you were trying to do. The reason it works is because `pmap()` takes a list of lists and all the lists have to be of the same length or equal to 1 (in which case, they are recycled). If you don't put your vector in `list()` before you put all 3 objects in a list, it won't work because the lengths of `df1` and `df2` is the number of columns (since data frames are lists of vectors), but the length of your vector is the number of its elements. Once you have put your vector in a list, the length of that list is 1 and it gets recycled. And it works.

Comment: In other words, passing `list(df1, vector1, df2)` into `pmap()` doesn't work because your `vector1` is not of the same length of your data frames, and if it, by chance, happened to be of the same length, you would not at all get what you expect as you would use each element of the vector at each iteration. By passing `vector1` itself into `list()`, it becomes a list of 1 which gets recycled and used in full at each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

No need for mapping or lists, simply run arithmetic on entire objects in base R. Below `rep` is needed for equal-length addition which simply repeats *vector1* 5 times for each column.

```
(x + y) ^ z
...
(df1 + rep(vector1, length(df1))) ^ df2
```

To return final column sums, run `colSums` which is a wrapper to `apply(..., 2, sum)`. But similar to @nicola in comments, I am unable to reproduce your desired result from posted values.

```
result <- (df1 + rep(vector1, length(df1))) ^ df2

colSums(result)
# variable_1 variable_2 variable_3 variable_4 variable_5 
#   15.08225  125.27506   13.09822   22.49251   30.75699 

apply(result, 2, sum)
# variable_1 variable_2 variable_3 variable_4 variable_5 
#   15.08225  125.27506   13.09822   22.49251   30.75699
```

---

Above is equivalent to `mapply` (of which `Map` is its non-simplified wrapper). But again elementwise iteration is not needed.

```
simple_function <- function(x,y,z) {
  sum((x + y) ^ z)
}
mapply(simple_function, df1, vector1, df2)
# variable_1 variable_2 variable_3 variable_4 variable_5 
#   15.08225  125.27506   13.09822   22.49251   30.75699

Map(simple_function, df1, vector1, df2)
# $variable_1
# [1] 15.08225

# $variable_2
# [1] 125.2751

# $variable_3
# [1] 13.09822

# $variable_4
# [1] 22.49251

# $variable_5
# [1] 30.75699
```